# Many to many relation custom table fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm working with typeorm on an already existing database.
I have three tables

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        ROLE                             |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| r_id        | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| r_name      | varchar(50)  |                            |
| r_status    | tinyint      |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        PERMISSION                       |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| p_id        | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| p_name      | varchar(50) |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                       PERMISSION_ROLE                   |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| p_id        | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
| r_id        | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY    |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

I wrote these entities in typeorm
-ROLE

```
@Entity({ name: "ROLE" })
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public r_id: Number;
  @Column()
  public r_nome_ruolo: string;
  @Column()
  public r_stato: Boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => PermissionRole, (permission_role) => permission_role.permission)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "r_id" })
  permission_role: PermissionRole[];
}
```

- PERMISSION

```
@Entity({ name: "PERMISSION" })
export class Permission {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public p_id: Number;
  @Column()
  public p_nome_permesso: string;
  @OneToMany(() => PermissionRole, (permission_role) => permission_role.permission)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "p_id" })
  permission_role: PermissionRole[];
}
```

- PERMISSION_ROLE

```
@Entity({ name: "PERMISSION_ROLE" })
export class PermissionRole {
  @ManyToOne(() => Permission, (permission: Permission) => permission.p_id, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "p_id" })
  permission: Permission;
  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role: Role) => role.r_id, { primary: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "r_id" })
  role: Role;
}
```

Problem is that I'm not able to retrive data from relations.
If I try something like this:

```
permissionRepository.find({ relations: ["permission_role"] })
```

or

```
roleRepository.find({ relations: ["permission_role"] })
```

I received permission_role in results but has an empty array.

Thank in advance to everyone will help

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I modified entity Role and Permission like this:

```
@Entity({  name: "ROLE" })
export class Role {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public r_id: Number;
  @Column()
  public r_nome_ruolo: string;
  @Column()
  public r_stato: Boolean;


  @ManyToMany(() => Permission, (permission) => permission.roles)
  @JoinTable({
    name: "PERMISSION_ROLE",
    joinColumn: {
      name: "r_id",
      referencedColumnName: "r_id",
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "p_id",
      referencedColumnName: "p_id",
    },
  })
  permissions: Permission[];
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: "PERRMISSION" })
export class Permission {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public p_id: Number;
  @Column()
  public p_nome_permesso: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Role, (role) => role.permissions)
  public roles: Role[];
}
```